# Optimal way to find neighbors of element of collection in circular manner

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `Vector` and I'd like to find neighbors of given element.

Say if we have `Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and then:

- for element `2`, result must be `Some((1, 3))`
- for element `5`, result must be `Some((4, 1))`
- for element `1`, result must be `Some((5, 2))`
- for element `6`, result must be `None`

and so on..

I have not found any solution in standard lib(please point me if there is one), so got the next one:

```
implicit class VectorOps[T](seq: Vector[T]) {
  def findNeighbors(elem: T): Option[(T, T)] = {
    val currentIdx = seq.indexOf(elem)
    val firstIdx = 0
    val lastIdx = seq.size - 1
    seq match {
      case _ if currentIdx == -1 || seq.size < 2 => None
      case _ if seq.size == 2 => seq.find(_ != elem).map(elem => (elem, elem))
      case _ if currentIdx == firstIdx => Some((seq(lastIdx), seq(currentIdx + 1)))
      case _ if currentIdx == lastIdx => Some((seq(currentIdx - 1), seq(firstIdx)))
      case _ => Some((seq(currentIdx - 1), seq(currentIdx + 1)))
    }
  }
}
```

The question is: how this can be simplified/optimized using stdlib?

Comment: You can get rid of the pattern matching as you don't use any pattern. A bunch of if else might be clearer.

Comment: Actually why this question has 2 minuses? It's better to provide some comment with rational critic about "how question was been asked" when you do it. I do no see any objective reason yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def neighbours[T](v: Seq[T], x: T): Option[(T, T)] =
  (v.last +: v :+ v.head)
    .sliding(3, 1)
    .find(_(1) == x)
    .map(x => (x(0), x(2)))
```

This uses `sliding` to create a 3 element window in the data and uses `find` to match the middle value of the 3. Adding the last/first to the input deals with the wrap-around case.

This will fail if the `Vector` is too short so needs some error checking.

---

This version is safe for all input

```
def neighbours[T](v: Seq[T], x: T): Option[(T, T)] =
  (v.takeRight(1) ++ v ++ v.take(1))
    .sliding(3, 1)
    .find(_(1) == x)
    .map(x => (x(0), x(2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Tim, it looks much better! But it fails on `neighbours(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)` - result is `None` but  the correct one is `Some((5,2))`.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Optimal when number of calls with the same sequence is about or more than seq.toSet.size:

```scala
val elementToPair = seq.indicies.map(i => seq(i) -> 
  (seq((i - 1 + seq.length) % seq.length), seq((i + 1 + seq.length) % seq.length)
).toMap
elementToPair.get(elem)
// other calls
```

Optimal when number of calls with the same sequence less than seq.toSet.size:

```scala
Some(seq.indexOf(elem)).filterNot(_ == -1).map { i => 
 (seq((i - 1 + seq.length) % seq.length), seq((i + 1 + seq.length) % seq.length) }
```